# How to create a scope around an object for quick access in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I can't find a way to express what I want in few words, so the title might not be as accurate as I wanted to (don't hesitate to help me rephrase it) but here is the explaination:

Let's say I have this object, bound to my Controller

```
  var ctrl = this;
  ctrl.myObject = {
    nested: {
      ppty: 1,
      otherPpty: 2
    },
    stuff: 'foo'
  }
```

What I'd like to do in the HTML

```
  <div ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
    <div class="divOfInterest" ng-something="myCtrl.myObject.nested as o">
      <span> Ppty: {{o.ppty}}</span>
      <span> otherPpty: {{o.otherPpty}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So I don't need to prefix `myCtrl.myObject.nested.ppty` when I'm in the `divOfInterest`.

I know that can be done with directives but since I won't reuse it somewhere else I'd just like to get a shortcut to some object in my controller.

Any idea how to perform that ?

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible without having extra controllers.

Comment: Alternatively I guess you could use ng-repeat and one-element arrays.

Comment: Actually, thinking about this some more... why not just create a property on your controller with the nested property?  Like `ctrl.o = myObject.nested`?

Comment: What is the provlem for navigating through the object hierarchy? If there is a problem, just add a reference in your controller to the `myCtrl.myObject.nested` for your `divOfInterest` like `ctrl.forDivOfInterest = ctrl.myObject.nested;` and use ctrl.forDivOfInterest

Comment: Thanks for your answers, that's also what I came out with but I was hoping Angular has a built-in directive for this use-case. I'll keep doing this, it does not add too much code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think `ng-init` might help you in this case.

`ng-init="o = myCtrl.myObject.nested  "`

Comment: It would probably work in my case but the doc states it should be used in only two cases, and mine is not one of them so I'll keep doing as Casey and Hamlet suggested. Thanks for your answer.